# How to fire events of child nodes of treeview control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page i have one treeview control in which i add child controls dynamically.So how to fire click event of child node.

Thanks.

Comment: Try if anything named ItemClick

Comment: Depends on when you created the child controls. If you created them after Page.Load() you can not get their events. ([ASP.NET page-lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=VS.100).aspx)) or you need to use JavaScript. Use the AttributeCollection.Add-method to append JavaScript [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection(v=vs.100).aspx)